# Flutter: How to make a page wait until data loads?

Tags: flutter, variables, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I used async while using the database, however, the page loads before the data. On the page a lot of widgets are connected to the `trophyPoint` variable and the page loads before the variable. I used `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` where the bottom navigation bar is located. It worked for the slide navigations, but when I tapped the navigation bar items, the variable returns null at first and it is the problem.

Edit: I also tried using the `SharedPreferences` class to load old data but it didn't work either.

Code

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {


 static String id = "MainScreen";

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int trophyPoint = 0;
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _future = Firebase.initializeApp();
  //Database instance
  final _db = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child("users")
      .child(_auth.currentUser.uid);

//method for data
  void readData(
    _db,
  ) async {
    await _db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        trophyPoint = snapshot.value["tp"];
      });
    });
  }

/*  void tp() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      geciciTP = sharedPreferences.getInt("trophy");
      sharedPreferences.setInt("geciciTP", geciciTP);
    });
  }*/

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    readData(_db);
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    precacheImage(AssetImage('images/indicator.gif'), context);
    return buildContainer(size, context);
  }

  Container buildContainer(Size size, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: kGradientColor,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          initialData: trophyPoint,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          right: size.width / 25,
                          top: size.height / 60,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: size.height * 0.055,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                              color: kDefaultLightColor,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  FontAwesomeIcons.trophy,
                                  color: Color(0xffFFD700),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "   $trophyPoint",
                                  ...
```

[gif file of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLHQ9.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) you can check:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
  return body....
} else {
  return CircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

The example at the link is pretty good.